# Importing data from CSV file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv

I have created a table called *StatesandCities* with 3 columns: *CountryCode*(its a foreign key), *State* and *City*, like shown below:

```
create table StatesandCities (CountryCode varchar(2), State varchar(20), city varchar(20),foreign key (CountryCode) references ListOfCountries (CountryCode));
```

I have a .CSV file with all the values:

```
CountryCode,State,City
IN,Karnataka,Bangalore
IN,Karnataka,Mysore
IN,Karnataka,Tumkur
IN,Maharashtra,Mumbai
IN,Maharashtra,Thane
IN,Maharashtra,Nasik
GB,Yorkshire,County Hill
GB,SouthWales,Murrey
```

And this is exactly how it appers in an Excel sheet:

```
CountryCode State   City
IN  Karnataka   Bangalore
IN  Karnataka   Mysore
IN  Karnataka   Tumkur
IN  Maharashtra Mumbai
IN  Maharashtra Thane
IN  Maharashtra Nasik
GB  Yorkshire   County Hill
GB  SouthWales  Murrey
```

I used this code to input the CSV file in MySQL 5.6 command-line client:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H:/Statesncities.csv' INTO TABLE StatesandCities FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines (CountryCode, State, City);
```

The values are getting entered but they are not in the right table format I need. And also if the data value is long its getting cut. It's all mixed up:
I've tried like changing the screen size, page layout, nothing seems to work.

[image: OUTPUT]

OUTPUT:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H:/countries.csv' INTO TABLE ListOfCountries
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES (CountryName, CountryCode);
```

I'm using `IGNORE 1 LINES` to skip CSV header line. I'd also turned `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` optionally.

You can refer to [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) section of MySQL manual for more details.

Comment: @confused Well, then your CSV file isn't formatted as you stated. Please, check your CSV file and update the question with any new relevant details. :)

Comment: @confused Your CSV file didn't seem to be formatted exactly as described here. Could you please check if you described it correctly? The CSV piece you pasted here should work as expected.

Comment: @confused I mean your CSV data, the lines you pasted in your question seems Ok (I've tested my answer with them), but if your importing isn't working, other lines of your file might be different than expected...

Comment: @confused Could you please remove your comment and paste all the CSV content in the question itself? Here it doesn't preserve formatting...

Comment: @confused Ermm, this doesn't seem to be the same CSV data as before... where is `CountryName`?

Comment: @confused So you're asking another question? I'm totally missed... Could you please edit your question with both questions, table structures and CSV data? Maybe I can help you better that way...

Answer (score 0):

`this should do it !!`

```
BULK INSERT mycountry
        FROM 'C:\CSVmydata\country.csv'
        WITH
        (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVmydata_error\countryErrorRows.csv',
        TABLOCK
        )
```

Comment: He asked for MySQL, not MS-SQL.

Comment: ye.. use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc` insted of bulkinsert in mysql

Comment: I did use that earlier.